# jquery mobile change page is not running in cordova

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I tried to make a list of the database and when I click supposed to move to the new page but not walk , can help me ?

This my index.html

```
<div data-role="page" id="display">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a target="_blank" href="#home" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">Home</a>
        <h1>Data Buku</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="tblDiv"></ul>
      </div>
</div>  

<div data-role="page" id="detail">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a target="_blank" href="#display" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left">All</a>
        <h1>Detail Buku</h1>
      </div>

      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <label for="noqr">QR Code :</label> <input disabled="disabled" name="noqr" id="noqr" type="text" />
            <label for="judul">Judul Buku :</label> <textarea disabled="disabled" name="judul" id="judul" ></textarea>
            <label for="pengarang">Pengarang Buku :</label> <textarea disabled="disabled" name="pengarang" id="pengarang" ></textarea>
            <label for="jilid">Jilid :</label> <input disabled="disabled" name="jilid" id="jilid" type="text" />
            <label for="tahun">Tahun :</label> <input disabled="disabled" name="tahun" id="tahun" type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

This my javascript

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

```
function populateDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BUKU (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, noqr,judul,pengarang,jilid,tahun)');
}

function detailDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT judul FROM BUKU where judul = "'+ document.getElementById("judul").value +'"', 
            [], getData, errorCB1);
}

function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        var datalist='<ul>';
        var len = results.rows.length;
           for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var tmpArgs= results.rows.item(i).id
                   +  ",'" + results.rows.item(i).noqr
                   + "','" + results.rows.item(i).judul
                   + "','" + results.rows.item(i).pengarang
                   + "','" + results.rows.item(i).jilid
                   + "','" + results.rows.item(i).tahun+"'";                
                datalist +='<li><a href="javascript:goDetail('" + results.rows.item(i).judul + "')"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">' + results.rows.item(i).judul +'</h3><p class="ui-li-desc">'+ results.rows.item(i).pengarang +'</li>';
        }
            datalist +="</ul>";
            document.getElementById("tblDiv").innerHTML = datalist;
}

function getData (tx, results) {
    var name = results.rows.item(0).noqr;
    var data = results.rows.item(0).judul;

        document.getElementById("noqr").innerHTML = noqr;
        document.getElementById("judul").innerHTML = judul;
    $.mobile.changePage("#detail");
} 

function errorCB1(err) {
    alert("erros pas where: "+err.code);
}

function goDetail() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Buku", 200000);
    db.transaction(detailDB,  errorCB1);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Buku", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your database name is `Database` ?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain, yes I am sure because when I store data and display data appears on the list , but when clicked do not move to the new page

Comment: Maybe it it not reaching `changePage` due to an error beforehand. Use Chrome Dev tools to debug by placing breakpoints on each function: http://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-android/